# Why does the TensorFlow tf.data.Dataset.shuffle function's reshuffle_each_iteration boolean argument default to None, as opposed to True?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

The [documentation for the tf.Dataset.data.shuffle function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) states the following:

> - **reshuffle_each_iteration**: (Optional.) A boolean, which if true indicates that the dataset should be pseudorandomly reshuffled each time it is iterated over. (Defaults to True.)

However, the default value in the function is None, as mentioned on the same page and in [the actual code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L590):

```
def shuffle(self, buffer_size, seed=None, reshuffle_each_iteration=None):
```

The function calls the ShuffleDataset class, whose `__init__` function also [sets the same argument to None by default](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L1245), and [uses the following logic](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L1292) to set the default value of the argument to True:

```
if reshuffle_each_iteration is None:
  self._reshuffle_each_iteration = True
else:
  self._reshuffle_each_iteration = reshuffle_each_iteration
```

Why isn't the argument just set to True by default in both the function and the class? This would make the above code block redundant and allow replacing it with only `self._reshuffle_each_iteration = reshuffle_each_iteration`.

Comment: Unless there is usage somewhere else, it probably should be replaced. Maybe submit a pull request?

Comment: I went ahead and did so here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/16810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by @mrry [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/16810#issuecomment-363918187.):

> - In general I prefer None for default arguments, because it makes it easier to write wrappers around an API. If the default argument is set to True, it's difficult for a wrapper to use the default of the wrapped function, without making a copy of the default at each layer of wrapping. Using None and implementing the default at the innermost level is simpler to maintain.
> - Using None is also consistent with the necessary style when the default argument can be a mutable type (like a list) and it is unsafe to put the default value in the argument list.